# Dynamic meta head title cache problem using Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, meta-tags

I have a composable, that fetches and stores a global variable:

```
// useRandomEmoji.ts

export default async function() {
  const { data, refresh, execute } = await useAsyncData(
    'randomEmoji', 
    () => $fetch("/api/emojis/random"),
    { immediate: false }
  )

  if (!data.value) execute()

  return { 
    randomEmoji: data, 
    refreshRandomEmoji: refresh 
  }
}
```

Then, I dynamicaly assign head title, whenever the value changes, it should change only on page reload:

```
// app.vue

const { randomEmoji } = await useRandomEmoji()

watch(() => randomEmoji.value, () => {
  useHead({ 
    title: `Nuxt ESR Emojis ${parseEmoji(randomEmoji.value?.htmlCode)}` 
  })
})
```

It works fine, but, if you:

1. navigate to the other page via link;
2. refresh the page;
3. and navigate through browser's go back or go forward buttons, head title will show previous value;
4. and if you return to the page where actual value was requested, it will show the actual value.

Seems like the browser remembered on each page what the title was. However, in the html inspect mode, head title shows actual value on every page.

What I've tried:

1. checked for missed state changes, it doesn't;
2. looked up for useNuxtData to log cached value along with useAsyncData's value, everytime they showed same synced value;
3. update head title on route change (even though it doesn't seem like a good practice), it didn't work either;
4. directly set document.title, no result.

You can reproduce it here:
https://nuxt-esr-emojis.pages.dev

Source code:
https://github.com/frontendlegend/nuxt-esr-emojis

Browser used: Google Chrome

How can I make a browser tab show the actual head title on every page, even when you reload on the other page and navigate with browser buttons?

Answer (score 0):

The issue arises due to browsers caching the page, including its title, when navigating using the back and forward buttons. Even though Nuxt updates the `document.title` correctly on the client side, the browser tab may not always reflect it instantly.

So, by adding a simple watch, you can directly set `document.title`. Whenever your data changes, update the browser title directly:

```
watch(() => randomEmoji.value, (newValue) => {
  document.title = `Nuxt ESR Emojis ${parseEmoji(newValue?.htmlCode)}`;
}, { immediate: true });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! Unfortunately it didn't work. Also there is a thing, that document is undefined on the server-side, but I've managed that by adding isMounted variable. I tried to directly set document.title, in the watch for route change and being mounted (running on the client-side). Still, browser keeps caching titles on every page.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it does not work it is because you are calling the `useRandomEmoji` composable in the main component.

If I understand it correctly, the main component will only trigger once. And that is when you refresh the page. If you temporarily disable the SSR in the `nuxt.config.ts`, you'll see all the APIs that are called in your app in the network tab.

When you refresh the page, you'll see the `random` API called in the network tab but when you go to the other pages, it does not called.

To fix that,

You can use the `titleTemplate` meta object in the `useHead` composable. So you don't need to repeat adding the `Nuxt ESR Emojis` string on every page.

`app.vue`

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtPage />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
useHead({
  titleTemplate(title) {
    return title ? `Nuxt ESR Emojis` : 'Nuxt ESR Emojis'
  },
})
</script>
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
}
</style>
```

`~/composables/useRandomEmoji.ts`

In your `useRandomEmoji` composable, remove the `{ immediate: false }` and the other unnecessary codes.

```js
export default async function () {
  const { data } = await useAsyncData(
    'randomEmoji',
    () => $fetch("/api/emojis/random")
  )
  return {
    randomEmoji: data,
  }
}
```

In the pages, add this codes inside the `script` setup

```js
const { randomEmoji } = await useRandomEmoji()
useHead({
  title: parseEmoji(randomEmoji.value?.htmlCode)
})
```

If you follow this, don't forget to disable the SSR in the `nuxt.config.ts`.

Tested and it works!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for reply! randomEmoji composable should be called only once on the first render or reload. Your solution mutates initial idea, by requesting new title on every page. By the way, didn't see any difference by toggling ssr in the config, but still want to keep app in the ssr mode. Appreciate the tip on titleTemplate, tried to add this part of your solution to assign title for each page, didn't help.